# Java - Print statement in for loop not printing anything

Tags: java, for-loop, println

I wrote simple for loop to print the first character from the beginning of the string then first character from the end.. etc, but the print statement doesn't show anything, why?

```
public class JavaOOP {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String string = "abca";

        for(int i=0,j=string.length()-1;i<string.length()/2+1 && j>string.length()/2+1;i++,j--){
            System.out.println(string.charAt(i)+ " " + string.charAt(j));
        }
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the starting and ending points of the loop.
string.length() is 4, so j starts from 3, and the condition to run is for it to be greater than 4/2+1=3. Since 3 is not greater than 3, it doesn't run a single iteration.

Comment: I've the *feeling* there must be an easier way to write the condition for that loop, maybe just comparing `i` and `j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the loop.

> *"... the print statement doesn't show anything, why?"*

This is because the second conditional statement, of the for-loop conditional statement, is never met, thus the loop never iterates.

```java
j>string.length()/2+1
```

You can capture the last value using the *[String#length](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length())* value.

Keep in mind, since the characters are referenced using a 0-based index, the last character is going to be the length, minus 1.

```java
String string = "abca";
char first = string.charAt(0);
char last = string.charAt(string.length() - 1);

System.out.println(first + " " + last);
```

Output

```
a a
```

You *could* use a loop to capture the first and last character, recursively.

```java
void traverse(String string) {
    if (string.length() <= 1) return;
    System.out.println(string.charAt(0) + " " + string.charAt(string.length() - 1));
    traverse(string.substring(1, string.length() - 1));
}
```

Example output, when *string* is, *"stack overflow"*.

```
s w
t o
a l
c f
k r
  e
o v
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that j starts at 3 and the condition checks while j is greater than 3 in this case, so the loop won't run.

Also notice that the two conditions can be simplified to `i <= j`.

```
abcd:
a d
b c

abcde:
a e
b d
c c
```

```java
public class JavaOOP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "abcd";

        for(int i=0, j=string.length() - 1; i <= j; i++,j--) {
            System.out.println(string.charAt(i) + " " + string.charAt(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: float operations and `ceil` is kind of an *overkill* here - just add one and then divide by 2 (all integers) ((assuming posed condition matches problem))

Comment: [Déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76501520/java-print-statement-in-for-loop-not-printing-anything#comment134887468_76501520) .... and you probably want `i <= j` to get posted output (last line `c c`) || BTW `string[i]` will not work with Java `String`

Comment: "*Optionally you can also simplify the .charAt(x) to be [x]*" - not with Java, unless you do `char[] string = "abcd".toCharArray();` or similar :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need two variables:

```
String input = /* some input */;
int len = input.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    System.out.println(input.charAt(i) + " " + input.charAt(len - 1 - i));
}
if (len % 2 == 1) { //account for middle character in odd-length string
    System.out.println(" " + input.charAt(len / 2)); //spaces it "in the middle"
}
```

In essence, you're using the symmetry of the `String`. You need characters the same distance from the ends of the strings (at indices `0` and `input.length() - 1`). So `i` is your distance from the ends, calculated as and simplified from `0 + i` and `input.length() - 1 - i`.

This results in (without repeating the characters in an odd-length string):

```
Input: abcde
a e
b d
 c

Input: abcdef
a f
b e
c d
```